# VBA macro select copy loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, copy-paste, do-while

I have some trouble with a macro I'm working on. 
See here for the data and the VBA macros: https://ufile.io/339xz

My excel looks this: 
[image: Is now]

I need it to look like this: 
[image: Should be]

The system goes like this:
1) for each 'husstr' a new line is made with a field for each houshold_order (fx a max of 4 fields for a household of a size 4)
2) the corresponding 'stilling i husstanden' for the household_order is moved to its place (eg. household order 1 in 'husstr' 1 goes to place 'stilling nr. 1')

The macro i've made works only on one household at a time, so I though I've would make a loop around it, but I cant seem to make it right.

Sub stack() moves the first three instances from husstr nr. 1 to the correct places (stilling nr. 1, stilling nr. 2 and stilling nr.3). That works perfectly! So fine.

```
    Sub stack()
Dim i As Integer
i = 2

Dim placering As Integer
placering = 6

Dim maxloop As Integer
maxloop = Cells(i, 3).Value + 1

For i = 2 To maxloop

    Cells(i, 2).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Cells(2, placering).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    placering = placering + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

My trouble starts when I want to loop through the different 'husstr'-types.
I've tried to solve it like this for the full dataset (contains 300K lines in all). I've made to sets of loops.

The first sub i the bigger loop:

```
Sub stilling_loop()
Dim k As Integer
k = 2

Dim i As Integer
i = 2

Dim checkhusst As Integer
checkhusst = 1

Do While i < 50
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = checkhusst Then Call fejl
    checkhusst = checkhusst + 1
    k = k + Cells(k, 3).Value
    i = k

Loop
End Sub
```

And the next sub is the smaller loop:

```
Sub fejl()
Dim o As Integer
o = 2

Dim placering As Integer
placering = 6

Dim maxloop As Integer
maxloop = Cells(o, 3).Value + 1

Dim række As Interior
rakke = 2

For i = 2 To maxloop

    Cells(i, 2).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Cells(rakke, placering).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    placering = placering + 1
Next i

placering = 6
i = i + Cells(o, 3).Value
rakke = rakke + 1
o = o + Cells(o, 3).Value

End Sub
```

It doesn't look like I can upload the excel here, so I've posted it here:
https://ufile.io/339xz

Comment: Not sure if this is causing the issue, but it's never a bad idea to try to avoid using select. If you're just changing values, you could set them directly `Cells(x,y).Value = Cells(x2,y2).Value` or you could use the destination parameter of copy `Cells(x,y).copy destination:= Cells(x2,y2)`. Also you've dimmed rakke with æ but reference it with a plain a in your code. including Option explicit at the top would've caught that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, so please work on a copy of your file:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

For i = 2 to ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If Range("A" & i).value <> Range("A" & i - 1).value then
        j = i
        Range("E" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).value
    Else
        Range("E" & j).Offset(0, i - j).Value = Range("B" & i).Value
    End if
Next i
```

Comment: The code works perfect! Depending which column the values should be located at (if post id should exist or not), OP might need to change `Range("E" & j)` -> `Range("F" & j)` and `Range("E" & i)` -> `Range("F" & i)`

Comment: Thank you both! Cybernetic.nomads code work perfectly and Wizhi was right too. Thank you so much!